# Meaning of "Get a purge for your brain. It will do better than for your stomach."

Tags: idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning, meaning

I read the following quote today from a book about productivity:

> Get a purge for your brain. It will do better than for your stomach.

I know that the first sentence talks about noting down all the pending items we have to do in some sort of physical physical (such as on paper or digitally). This is the "purge" part. It purges all these nagging concerns about things to be done from the brain to a physical medium.

But I do not understand what the second sentence means. Does it only mean that the way we purge our brain is going to be better than how we purge our stomach (by defecation)? Or does it mean that purging our brains will be good for our stomach and thus for our overall health?

Comment: To simplify but not clarify: Purge your head, not your tummy. It's a strange one and doesn't sound colloquial. Marketing of sorts. Also, stomachs are not purged downwards but by upchucking.

Comment: "purge" as in something that induces vomiting, an *emetic* (see: ipecac syrup).

Comment: https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Essays_of_Michael_Seigneur_de_Montai/C24RAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Get+a+purge+for+your+brain&pg=PA466&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Purge can also refer to the use of a laxative to evacuate stomach contents in the other direction; [laxatives are sometimes called purgatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laxative).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kind of a joke.

To purge is to quickly remove unwanted material. If you purge your brain, you clear out unnecessary thoughts. If you purge your stomach, you remove things that you've eaten that cause indigestion or sickness -- the most common way to do this is to vomit.

So they're saying that clearing your mind will solve your indigestion problems caused by stress better than vomiting.